# Angular Universal Hydration

Tags: angular, angular-universal, hydration

I started an Angular 16 project without Server-Side Rendering (SSR). Now, I needed to add SSR to it. I successfully added 'nguniversal' and could run it using 'npm run dev:ssr,' which gave me a link I could access. However, when I followed the documentation to add Hydration by using 'provideClientHydration()' in my 'app.module' and rerunning it in SSR mode, the link opened a blank page with infinite loading and no error messages. I searched the internet for a solution, tried various things, and even reinstalled the package, but I couldn't find a solution because there were no error messages or clues. Has anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: Did you get any error on Browser console?

Comment: @aaqib90 No, not at all. Only an infinite loading page when open the project locally with ssr, with the provideClientHydration() added to the app.module providers. When I remove it, the infinite loading stops and everything works fine.

Comment: I've got the same issue. Did you happe. To resolve this?